# What are the problems in the following code?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

There is an error in line 23 (expected ')' before '{' token) and in line 37 (cannot convert '' to 'int' in assignment), how may I solve theese? (The function of the program is to find how many triangles could be made by using N number of sticks(you must use every stick)).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a,b,c,db=0,n, i, j, k;
bool already = false;

int main()
{
    cout << "n = ";
    cin >> n;

    int myarray[n][n][n];

    for(a = 1; a < n; a++){
        for(b = 1; b < n; b++){
            for(c = 1; c < n; c++){
                if(a+b>c && a+c>b && c+b>a && a+b+c==n){
                    while(!already){
                        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
                            for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
                                for(k = 0; k < n; k++){
                                    if(myarray[i][j][k] == {{a},{b},{c}} || myarray[i][j][k] == {{a},{c},{b}} || myarray[i][j][k] == {{b},{a},{c}} || myarray[i][j][k] == {{b},{c},{a}} || myarray[i][j][k] == {{c},{a},{b}} || myarray[i][j][k] == {{c},{b},{a}}){
                                        already = true;
                                        cout <<myarray[i][j][k];
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(already == false){
                    cout << "db's actual value: " << db << endl;
                    cout << "A= " << a << " B= " << b << " C= " << c << endl;
                    }
                myarray[i][j][k] = {{a}, {b}, {c}};
                already = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << db <<" triangles could be made. " <<endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: which lines are 23 and 37 ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this `{{a},{b},{c}}` syntax?

Comment: `myarray[i][j][k]` is an `int`, not three numbers.

Comment: 7 loops depth? Really?

Comment: `initializer list cannot be used on the right hand side of operator '=='`

Comment: Your biggest problem is number of nested blocks of code, but what do you expect `myarray[i][j][k] == {{a},{b},{c}} ` to do?

Comment: not the error, but it seems like you only ever use a single entry in this 3d monster array (namely `myarray[i][j][k]`). Assuming your logic is correct otherwise you should consider replacing it with a single `int`

Comment: ...well somehow your logic cannot be correct, you are trying to access `myarray[i][j][k]` outside of the loops for `i`,`j` and `k`, which is basically accessing `myarray[n][n][n]` which is out-of-bounds. Imho the primary problem in your code is too much complexity. Try to split it into simpler functions. ymmv but imho >3 levels of nesting arent really made for humans to read or understand

Comment: Your (second, after Yksisarvinen's mention) biggest problem is that this is not valid C++: `int myarray[n][n][n];` is not legal with n being a non compile time constant.

Comment: Here are two alternative error outputs: https://godbolt.org/z/eQ9rsK Perhaps they can provide some more info than the `g++` output.

Comment: This gets a bit more complicated, if the sticks are allowed to overlap. You could post this in https://math.stackexchange.com/ I bet there is a formula for that.

Comment: "What are the problems in the following code?" umm... 9 levels of nested control structures, 7 of which are loops. And this is a bigger problem than whatever compiler errors you have.

Comment: IMHO, another problem in your code is variable names.  Compilers will discern up to  32 characters.  You have at least 32 character long names you can use.  That's a lot.  Make them more descriptive so readers can tell what your program is doing.

Comment: BTW, the `break` statement only exits out of the innermost loop.

Comment: The `cout <<myarray[i][j][k];` will print numbers next to each other without spaces or other delimiters.  For example, outputting 3 and 6 would appear as a single number 36.

Comment: You may want to use some math to determine if the three sides make a triangle.  For example, the lengths 20, 2, 5, will not make a triangle.  Your program is never looking at the lengths of the sides.

Comment: I recommend getting the program to work correctly before any optimizations; which includes checking of existing side values.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this output from g++ on Ubuntu compiled like this `g++ -std=c++11 wierd.cpp`:

```
wierd.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
wierd.cpp:23:60: error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token
                                     if(myarray[i][j][k] == {{a},{b},{c}} || myarray[i][j][k] == {{a},{c},{b}} || myarray[i][j][k] == {{b},{a},{c}} || myarray[i][j][k] == {{b},{c},
                                                            ^
```

Your problem here is you are using an initializer in comparison. I don't suppose it is legal even in C++11. Also you are comparing `myarray[i][j][k]` with a two-dimensional array which is not legal.

```
wierd.cpp:23:60: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘{’ token
wierd.cpp:37:34: error: cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘int’ in assignment
                 myarray[i][j][k] = {{a}, {b}, {c}};
```

The problem here is you are trying to assign a two-dimensional array (or better said its initializer) to a variable of type `int`. `myarray[i][j][k]` is in fact an element of type `int` in `myarray`.

Please note that this will also be illegal on the same line:

```
myarray = {{a}, {b}, {c}};
```

It is assigning to an array from an initializer list.

From the code and errors you post I don't suppose you know what `myarray` is.

`myarray` is of type `int[][][]`, which means that it is an array containing two-dimensional arrays of ints i.e. `int[][]`, so on each position you will have an array. Consequently for any valid a and b: `myarray[a][b]` contains one-dimensional arrays of ints i.e. `int[]`. And consequently for any valid a and b and c: `myarray[a][b][c]` contains a single int value.

Your code also does not explain what you are trying to do. Hence my answer only explains what is wrong. Maybe a separate quesion would help reach your goal.

EDIT

Your array initializers are two-dimensional, not three-dimensional. A correct initializer would be `{{{a}},{{b}},{{c}}}` which results in three ints being on the array and only those ints.

```
myarray[0][0][0] == a
myarray[1][0][0] == b
myarray[2][0][0] == c
```